# How to re-render without useEffect

Tags: reactjs, render

I am trying to find out how I can cause a re-render without forcing it by adding another dependency to the useEffect array.

```
    if (projectId) {
      dispatch(projectRoleActions.getAll({ filterProject: [projectId], include: PROJECT_ROLE_INCLUDES }))
    } else {
      dispatch(projectRoleActions.getAll({ include: PROJECT_ROLE_INCLUDES }))
    }
  }, [projectId, dispatch])
```

I tried setting a state to change when I add the first "role" to cause a re-render but didn't work.

```
const [firstRoleAdded, setFirstRoleAdded] = useState()
```

```
const handleCreateProjectRole = () => {
    setFirstRoleAdded(true)
    dispatch(projectRoleActions.create(
      {
        notes: '',
        project: projectId,
        allocation: 100,
        startDate: projectStartDate,
        endDate: projectEndDate,
      },
      {
        include: ['employee', 'employee.user', 'employee.employee-allocation-sequences']
      }
    ))
  }
```

Comment: You should rarely (or never) need to manually trigger a re-render. Components render when state or props change, or a parent re-renders. If any of these are not triggering a re-render, you probably have a mutation bug somewhere. What is the actual issue you are encountering?

Comment: No need actually. Just use the state variable in the render function.

Comment: @LikiCrus could you be more clear? Which render function?

Comment: @BrianThompson That makes sense. I have this timeline that won't render on the screen unless I add 2 or more items (roles) to that timeline. It doesn't render when I add the first one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.